# Will BigQuery be supported for the long haul?

Tags: google-bigquery

Since bigquery is out of labs, does that mean it will not be discontinued and is safe to invest time and resources in?

Simple question

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

Google is deeply invested in the Google Cloud Platform and in making it easy for developers to build, deploy and scale applications. We're committed to offering stable and relevant services to our community. This certainly includes BigQuery.